# Asynchronous code without Promise

Tags: java, asynchronous, playframework

Inside an Action, which is the best way to execute some asynchronous code if you don't need a Promise to produce the actual Result?

E.g I've created a RecordedAction to compose with other Actions. It executes an expensive operation (writes to the DB) but doesn't produce something needed by the annotated Action. In other words, I don't need a Promise but I do need a separate ExecutionContext.

I could do something like this:

```
public class RecordedAction extends Action<Recorded> {
    @Override
    public F.Promise<Result> call(Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        Promise.promise(() -> {
            // do asynchronous stuff
            return Promise.pure(null, myExecutionContext);
        });
        return delegate.call(ctx);
    }
}
```

But I'm just exploiting the Promise to use a separate ExecutionContext.